# кнопка назад Vs code pls help

Tags: кодировка, visual-studio-code

какой кнопка на Vs code назад (отменить)    примерна я написал код и удалил и какой кнопка будеть восстановить мой код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl + Z - отмена последних действий с кодом, одного за другим

Ctrl + Y - обратная операция, котрая вновь повторяет сделанные с кодом действия

Comment: СПС Болшой тебе

Comment: Ctrl + Y - обратная операция или Ctrl + Shift +Z